# 32Feet.NET. How to pair PC with a device?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, 32feet

I write an application for Windows Form. I have a problem with pairing a device with PC. Now the program works next way: switch on the divece, start the program, add divece to Bluetooth device, push connect button. I use the next functions:

```cs
    public BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
    public string selectedItem { get; set; }
    public BluetoothDeviceInfo[] AllDevices;

    public void GetDevices()
    {
        AllDevices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo Device in AllDevices)
        {
            if(Device.DeviceName.Contains("Kortes"))
                onSetDevices(Device.DeviceName); // event to get device name and add it to ComoBox element on form
        }
        onSetProgress(); // event, that all devices were found, set progress bar and etc.
    }
    public void GoConnect()
    {
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo Device in AllDevices)
        {
            if (Device.DeviceName.Equals(selectedItem)) // item from ComboBox
            {
                if (!client.Connected)
                    client = new BluetoothClient();
                client.BeginConnect(Device.DeviceAddress, Device.InstalledServices[0], this.BluetoothClientConnectCallback, client);
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose the device");
            }
        }
    }
    private void BluetoothClientConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //Have no problem with this
    }
```

These functions work very well. I can find and connect with needed device. But the problem is that firstly I need to add my device to Bluetooth device in OS and enter PIN code. How can I improve my code to solve this problem?

I don't want to add device. I want to work with it directly. Which methods can I use to enter PIN code programmatically? The program must work the next way: switch on the device, start the program, and push connect button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to connect without pairing.Your code is not working because you have to pair before connecting.

replace

```
client = new BluetoothClient();

client.BeginConnect(Device.DeviceAddress, Device.InstalledServices[0], this.BluetoothClientConnectCallback, client);
```

by

`BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(Device.DeviceAddress,"123456");`

Check out [http://mrbikash.com/bluetooth-discovery-pairing-32feet-net/#pairing](https://web.archive.org/web/20171112184322/http://mrbikash.com/bluetooth-discovery-pairing-32feet-net/#pairing) for a more detailed explanation.